# Checking text appears inside an element using react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing some tests for a React app using [Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/). I want to check that some text appears, but I need to check it appears in a particular place because I know it already appears somewhere else.

The [Testing Library documentation for queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#bytext) says that the `getByText` query takes a `container` parameter, which I guessed lets you search within that container. I tried doing this, with the `container` and `text` parameters in the order specified in the docs:

```
const container = getByTestId('my-test-id');
expect(getByText(container, 'some text')).toBeTruthy();
```

and I get an error: `matcher.test is not a function`.

If I put the params the other way round:

```
const container = getByTestId('my-test-id');
expect(getByText('some text', container)).toBeTruthy();
```

I get a different error: `Found multiple elements with the text: some text`

Which means it's not searching inside the specified container.

I think I'm not understanding how `getByText` works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can grab the text with `expect(container.textContent).toMatch('some text')`

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Better to use [`within`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-within/) for this sort of things:

```
render(<MyComponent />)
const { getByText } = within(screen.getByTestId('my-test-id'))
expect(getByText('some text')).toBeInTheDocument()
```

Comment: Following up the is s solution as getByText throw out error if text cannt find. Then what is the point to use expect....toBeInTheDocument?

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer as from documentation: ' Avoid destructuring queries from `render` result, use `screen.getByTestId` instead'

Comment: @carmine-tambascia, do you have a link to that quote in the docs? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @ddblair https://develop.sentry.dev/frontend/using-rtl/#:~:text=Avoid%20destructuring%20query%20functions%20from,take%20care%20of%20the%20rest.

Comment: @carmine-tambascia Thank you. Seems it's just a tip for the sake of the developer, though, and nothing more.

Comment: @carmine-tambascia Also, those are not the React Testing Library docs. The docs can be found [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/).

Comment: @ddblair "Seems it's just a tip for the sake of the developer," well that's what we are doing "here". On top, not sure why you are mentioning the React Testing library. the question is pretty simple.

Comment: @carmine-tambascia The question is tagged with "react-testing-library" lol. You said this shouldn't be the accepted answer because it's not following a guide from the docs, but you quoted the Sentry docs and it was only a suggestion even there. I just wanted to make it clear to future readers this answer is okay.

Comment: @ddblair ok I misread regarding the Testing library, got confused regarding another issue. Nevertheless, I stand with my previous message, maybe isn't a bad answer, but neither the one to get the attention as the accepted one. That'it. let's move one, there are better things to do.

Answer (score 80):

Another way to do this

```
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react';

...

  render(<MyComponent />);
  expect(screen.getByTestId('my-test-id')).toHaveTextContent('some text');
```

Note it is now recommended to use `screen` instead of the results of render.

(StackOverflow post the points to a KC Dobbs Article explaining why: [react-testing-library - Screen vs Render queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482418/react-testing-library-screen-vs-render-queries))

Comment: You may need to add `import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";` to access the `toHaveTextContent` matcher as described [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/379).

Comment: "...recommended to use screen..."
But y tho? Rather than pontificating, a link by Those Who Recommend would be appreciated.

Comment: Heres another SO post on screen vs render that points to a KC Dobbs explination:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482418/react-testing-library-screen-vs-render-queries

Comment: Unfortunately on toHaveTextContent I got ' Property 'toHaveTextContent' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement''

Comment: This is simple and works perfectly for me :) thanks

Comment: Seems like a much better solution than the accepted answer, which forces a particular coding style.

Answer (score 8):

This way you can be more precise, focusing in specific item:

```js
expect(queryByTestId("helperText")?.textContent).toContain("Help me!");
```